# how can i enable permissions to query tables in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have been denied access or permission to query tables in bigquery. i've been running queries wiythout issues until some days before when i started running sub-queries, whenever i try to run it, it brings out an error message telling me that my access has been denied and i dont have the permission to query that table or the location is not within US.

how can i enable permissions to query tables?
And how can i confirm the location of my dataset?

i have tried enabling permission by granting access through IAM roles and it still brings up this error message

this is the error message
Access Denied: Table your-project:warehouse_orders.orders: User does not have permission to query table your-project:warehouse_orders.orders, or perhaps it does not exist in location US.

Answer (score 0):

What roles have you granted to the user?

Should use "[BigQuery Data Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control?hl=es-419#bigquery.dataViewer)" for bringing access to view data.